# AnkhSVN Error in Visual Studio 2022 17.6.5

Tags: visual-studio-2022, ankhsvn

I,ve just updated VS 2022 to version 17.6.5 and now got the error "Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommonIDE.Solutions.SolutionPropertyBag' to type 'Ankh.Scc.Native.ICOMPropertyBag'."
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfZzL.png)
The version of AnkhSVN is the latest one (2.9.87.0)

Any ideas?

Thank you very much

I saw that there was the same problem with VS 17.2.5 and it was solved by the latest release of AnkhSVN